# How to import contacts from SIM to a different Windows Live account?

Tags: contacts, windows-live

I have a Windows Phone 7.8 handset. When I bought the phone, I configured it with my Windows Live account and instructed the phone to import all the contacts from the SIM card to the WL account. So far so good.

Now I would like to use my phone to sync the contacts on the SIM card of my wife (who has just a basic phone) to her WL account. So I had thought on setting up her WL account on my phone, then inserting her SIM card, then simply synchronizing the contacts from her SIM to her WL account.

However, I have noticed that the "Import contacts from SIM" option on the phone is always syncing data to my "primary" WL account, the one that I had set up when I first turned on the phone. It doesn't ask me which account should the contacts be imported to.

So the question is: is there a way to import SIM contacts to a *secondary* Windows Live account (an account registered in the phone after the initial setup) in Windows Phone 7.8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Because of the architecture of Windows Phone, you can perform certain things with your primary account that you can not do concurrently with the non-primary accounts.

Potentially, in the future, this may be something that is possible with Windows Phone 8.

Otherwise, your only option is to hard reset the phone, make your wife's account the primary account on the phone, import the contacts from her SIM into the primary account and then hard reset the phone again and go back to your original configuration.

Comment: Or: get the wife her own Windows Phone..

Comment: peSHIr: that's what I actually intend to do :-) But all the new phones use microSIM and she has currently a normal SIM. I must either ask for a new card to the phone carrier, or try to cut the existing card by myself, in which case I may break it. In either case I wanted to make a backup of all her contacts first.